# Combining objects with duplicate values inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

If I have an array of objects and there are certain objects that have the same name/property (in my case there are 2 instances of objects with a name of "highway"), how can I remove these objects from the array and add a new object with that contains data from both?

```
const data = [
    { "data": [ { "x": "sensor_error_code", "y": [ 0, 9 ] } ], "name": 123 },
    { "data": [ { "x": "road_type", "y": [ 15, 24 ] } ], "name": "city" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "road_type", "y": [ 0, 14 ] } ], "name": "highway" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "road_type", "y": [ 25, 30 ] } ], "name": "highway" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "weather", "y": [ 0, 8 ] } ], "name": "rain" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "weather", "y": [ 9, 24 ] } ], "name": "sun" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "special_object", "y": [ 5, 15 ] } ], "name": true }
];
```

e.g. having one instance of "highway" with a data object containing the values from both:

```
{ "data": [ { "x": "road_type", "y": [ 0, 14 ] }, { "x": "road_type", "y": [ 25, 30 ] } ], "name": "highway" }
```

So far I've tried to make a new empty object and loop over the data array, accumulating that empty object with names and values from that array. I was planning on converting that object to an array in the end. The code I've used is below:

```
const myData = {};
atts.forEach(att => {
  if (myData[att.name]) {
    myData[att.name].push(att.data)
  } else {
    myData[att.name] = att.data;
  }
})
console.log(myData)
```

However, the code I've used above involves some additional manipulation to make the data ready for consumption by a library and I was wondering if there are simpler ways to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution has a decent start. There are only 2 problems with your solution:

- You need to "unwrap" the array when pushing it
- You need to combine them all together at the end

```js
const myData = {};
atts.forEach(att => {
  if (myData[att.name]) {
    myData[att.name].push(...att.data) // Notice this change
  } else {
    myData[att.name] = att.data;
    // or if you don't want to alter the original data
    myData[att.name] = [...att.data]; // basically a shallow copy
  }
})
const result = [];
for (const key in myData) {
    result.push({ data: myData[key], name: key });
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce()` (to convert your array into an [aggregated value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) along with `.findIndex()` (this helps in finding if data from same category exists in the new array you are making)

```js
const atts = [
    { "data": [ { "x": "sensor_error_code", "y": [ 0, 9 ] } ], "name": 123 },
    { "data": [ { "x": "road_type", "y": [ 15, 24 ] } ], "name": "city" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "road_type", "y": [ 0, 14 ] } ], "name": "highway" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "road_type", "y": [ 25, 30 ] } ], "name": "highway" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "weather", "y": [ 0, 8 ] } ], "name": "rain" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "weather", "y": [ 9, 24 ] } ], "name": "sun" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "special_object", "y": [ 5, 15 ] } ], "name": true }
];


let myData = atts.reduce((agg, x) => {
  let isIndex = agg.findIndex(a => a.name == x.name);
  if(isIndex > -1) agg[isIndex].data.push(x.data[0]);
else {
agg.push({data : x.data , name : x.name});
}
return agg;
},[]);
console.log(myData)
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach using reduce - tracking the items by keys and merging the arrays of duplicate objects

```
const combined = Object.entries(data.reduce((b,a) => {
 // our result will be an object so wrap it in Object.entries so we can iterate through to finish
    if (b.hasOwnProperty(a.name)) b[a.name].data = [...b[a.name].data, ...a.data];
    // if the property exists, merge the 'y' array
    else b[a.name]=a;
    // otherwise add to the object
    return b;
    },{})).map(e => e[1])
    // finally map the result out to the desired format
```

```js
const data = [
    { "data": [ { "x": "sensor_error_code", "y": [ 0, 9 ] } ], "name": 123 },
    { "data": [ { "x": "road_type", "y": [ 15, 24 ] } ], "name": "city" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "road_type", "y": [ 0, 14 ] } ], "name": "highway" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "road_type", "y": [ 25, 30 ] } ], "name": "highway" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "weather", "y": [ 0, 8 ] } ], "name": "rain" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "weather", "y": [ 9, 24 ] } ], "name": "sun" },
    { "data": [ { "x": "special_object", "y": [ 5, 15 ] } ], "name": true }
];

const combined = Object.entries(data.reduce((b,a) => {
if (b.hasOwnProperty(a.name)) b[a.name].data[0].y = [...b[a.name].data[0].y, ...a.data[0].y];
else b[a.name]=a;
return b;
},{})).map(e => e[1])

console.log(combined)
```